# Taylor series of a function.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider a real infinitely differentiable function of a real variable, call it $f$. We do not know what $f$ is. Denote as $f^{(2n+1)}$ the $(2n+1)$th derivative of $f$ and denote by $c$ some positive real constant.

Consider the series:
$
S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^{(2n+1)}(x) \frac{1}{n!} c^n
$

Is it possible to find a closed-form/otherwise nice expression for $S(x)$ i.e. a finite composition of simple operations applied to $f(x)$ and $c$ (and possibly some finite number of higher derivatives)?

Does the problem become any simpler if $c=1$?

Comment: I don't suppose $f$ is analytic? I don't think there is a nice expression in any case. Apart from the case $c=x$, in which I guess you could say $S(x)$ is the odd part of $f(x)$.

Comment: I don't think so, but I have no proof.